# bash . moving files except files with a given suffix

Tags: unix, bash

Is there any way in bash to glob files that does not end with a certain suffix ?

e.g. I'm doing this:

mv $INCDIR/HDR_10_* $BACKUPDIR

But I don't want to move the HDR_10_* that ends with .gz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work for the file move:

```
mv $( echo $INCDIR/HDR_10_* | grep -v '\.gz$') $BACKUPDIR
```

You also asked 'to glob files that does not end with a certain suffix ?'
Bash has the shell option (shopt) extglob, which allows extended globbing syntax.  The `!(...glob...)` matches everything **but** the glob pattern.

```
shopt -s extglob
cd $INCDIR
mv !(*.gz) $BACKUPDIR
```

would work **only** if $INCDIR contained only files named HDR_10_*, specifically it would match any file or directory in $INCDIR that doesn't match *.gz.  Technically you're asking for a glob that both matches one pattern but not another, which i don't think exists as a simple single entity.

Comment: Your first command simply won't work, as the `echo` command puts all names on one line.

Comment: P.S. And if you try to fix that, you'll run into problems if a file name contains a special character such as whitespace or globbing characters.

Comment: Since the patterns (the one to include and the one to exclude) don't overlap, it's actually easy to combine them: `mv $INCDIR/HDR_10_!(*.gz) $BACKUPDIR`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `find`, `grep`, and `xargs`, you can do this fairly easily.

I am sure there are better constructions, but this is one that comes to mind right away:

```
# find <here>| <pattern>    | <notpattern>| <what to do>
find $INCDIR | grep HDR_10_ | grep -v .gz | xargs mv $BACKUPDIR
```

A correction was pointed-out in the comments that the above quick-stab won't work because of `mv` not getting its arguments in the proper order from `xargs`:

```
find $INCDIR -name 'HDR_10_*' ! -name '*.gz' -exec mv {} $BACKUPDIR \
```

Comment: You can't use `xargs` here - `xargs` adds parameters to the end, you need after `mv`.
Remember that `find` allows both positive and negative patterns as well.  Maybe something like:
`find $INCDIR -name 'HDR_10_*' ! -name '*.gz' -exec mv {} $BACKUPDIR \;`

Comment: Your command has many bugs. Beyond what Rich already said about `xargs`, the `grep` patterns are matching anywhere on the line, so they will include or exclude things that should not be (e.g. `HDR_10_agz.txt` will be excluded while `NOT_HDR_10_blah` will be included). It's possible to use `grep` here, but it's a lot simpler to use `-name` with `find` as per Rich's comment. Also your command will include files in subdirectories, which is not in the original specification. Then there is the generic problem with `xargs` requiring quoted output in a way that `find` can't produce.

Comment: @Gilles - yes, the behavior as currently written will search anywhere on the line: that's not a "bug" in my mind, but a starting place that could take refinement based on the specific use. Didn't know about the `xargs` issue till @Rich Homolka said something though :)

Comment: It's because of the issue with using `xargs` that (at least GNU) `mv` has `--target-directory=DIRECTORY` and `find` and `xargs` can use a null delimiter. So you can do `xargs ... -print0 | xargs -0 --target-directory="$BACKUPDIR"` and only get one copy of `mv` spawned (by not using `-I` with `xargs`).

Answer (score 1):

Under ksh, `!(*.gz)` matches all files in the current directory except the files that match `*.gz`. The same pattern works in bash after `shopt -s extglob`, and in zsh after `setopt ksh_glob`. Neither ksh nor bash has a way to take the intersection of a positive match and a negative match. In zsh, after `setopt extended_glob` , you can write `$INCDIR/HDR_10_*~$INCDIR/*.gz`.

One solution, in any Bourne-style shell (ash, bash, ksh, zsh, ...), is to iterate over the files and check each match.

```
for x in "$INCDIR"/HDR_10_*; do
  case "$x" in
    *.gz) :;;
    *) mv -- "$x" "$BACKUPDIR";;
  esac
done
```

Another solution is to use `find`. The following command will move files in subdirectories as well.

```
find "$INCDIR" -type f -name 'HDR_10_*' \! -name '*.gz' -exec mv {} "$BACKUPDIR" \;
```

If you have GNU find (e.g. under Linux), You can add `-maxdepth 1` after `"$INCDIR"` to move files only directly in `$INCDIR`.

Note that **You should always use double quotes around variable substitutions (e.g. `"$INCDIR"`, not `$INCDIR`)** unless you have a good reason to omit them. Otherwise you will run into trouble if you have files whose name contains special characters such as whitespace or `\[?*`.